# printing the correct value from a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get my list to print the total amount of temperatures that lie within the normal range (38.3 and 39.2). When it prints it just says the total amount is 0.0 but from the temperatures shown below it should be 50% any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
temperatures = [38.4, 38.5, 39.3, 39.1, 38, 36.5]

total_temperatures = len(temperatures)

normal_temperatures = 0

for temp in range(total_temperatures):
    if temp >= 38.3 and temp <= 39.2:
        normal_temperatures = normal_temperatures + 1


percentage = normal_temperatures * 100 / total_temperatures
percentage = round(percentage, 1)

print('The percentage of temperatures that lie within the normal range is', percentage)
```

Comment: You are doing `for temp in range(total_temperatures)`, so `temp` is the index, not the value.

Comment: you are iterating over `total_temperatures = len(temperatures)`, in which case `temp` variable will take values `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Change to `for temp in temperatures`

Comment: To debug small programs, [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) is a very useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `for temp in range(total_temperatures):` with `for temp in temperatures:` You want to compare the temperature values, not the index in a range.

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct code:

```
temperatures = [38.4, 38.5, 39.3, 39.1, 38, 36.5]

total_temperatures = len(temperatures)

normal_temperatures = 0
for temp in temperatures:
    if temp >= 38.3 and temp <= 39.2:
        normal_temperatures = normal_temperatures +1
percentage = normal_temperatures * 100 / total_temperatures
percentage = round(percentage, 1)

print('The percentage of temperatures that lie within the normal range is', percentage)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `sum()` and a generator comprehension to considerably shorten your code:

```
temperatures = [38.4, 38.5, 39.3, 39.1, 38, 36.5]

total_temperatures = len(temperatures)

normal_temperatures = sum(1 for t in temperatures if 38.3<= t <= 39.2)

percentage = normal_temperatures * 100 / total_temperatures
percentage = round(percentage, 1)

print('The percentage of temperatures that lie within the normal range is', percentage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use some list comprehension:

```
temperatures = [38.4, 38.5, 39.3, 39.1, 38, 36.5]
normal_temperatures = [x for x in temperatures if x>= 38.3 and x<= 39.2]
total_temperatures = len(temperatures)
normal_temp_len = len(normal_temperatures)
percentage = normal_temp_len*100/total_temperatures
percentage = round(percentage, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done that...:

```
temperatures = [38.4, 38.5, 39.3, 39.1, 38, 36.5]

total_temperatures = len(temperatures)

normal_temperatures = 0
print("DEBUG")
print(total_temperatures)

for temp in (temperatures):
    if temp >= 38.3 and temp <= 39.2:
        normal_temperatures = normal_temperatures + 1

print("DEBUG")
print(normal_temperatures)
print("DEBUG")

percentage = normal_temperatures * 100 / total_temperatures
percentage = round(percentage, 1)

print(f"The percentage of temperatures that lie within the normal range is', {percentage}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).